# file_get_contents(); no longer work with html table?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I was using a code that always worked for me when i need to get external html content but, since yesterday, the code no longer works.

Here´s the code setup

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$url ='https://www3.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultarTodasAsMoedas.do?method=consultaTodasMoedas';
$site = file_get_contents($url);
```

This link is a Currency Converter from Brazil Central Bank and have daily updates (Business Days).

I Need to get the USD and EUR values from this page, when i try to get values inside the Table it return empty but when i get values inside a div everything work as expected.

If i go to the page Source Code i can see:

```
<tr class="fundoPadraoBClaro2">
     <td align="CENTER">220</td>
     <td align="CENTER">A</td>
     <td align="CENTER">USD</td>
     <td align="right">2,2743</td>
     <td align="right">2,2748</td>
     <td align="right">1,0000</td>
     <td align="right">1,0000</td>
</tr>
```

To get the Dollar Value i use:

```
$data1 = explode('<td align="CENTER">USD</td><td align="right">', $site);
$data2 = explode('</td>',$data1[1]);
$usd = $data2[0];
```

But don´t work, this returns empty values.

But if i use the same code to get contents inside a DIV everything Works ok.

Source Code:

```
<div align="center">
    <strong>Cotações de todas as moedas no dia 09/08/2013 às 13:00 (horário de Brasília), conforme fechamento PTAX.</strong>
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```
$data1 = explode('todas as moedas no dia', $site);
$data2 = explode('conforme fechamento PTAX.',$data1[1]);
$result = $data2[0];
```

I get what i expected - "09/08/2013 às 13:00 (horário de Brasília)"

Can anyone tell me what i´m missing ?

Comment: Why are you screen scraping when the site provides a csv for you to access?

Comment: Because sometimes the CSV file is not updated at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not taking the whitespace between `<td align="CENTER">USD</td>` and `<td align="right">` into account.

This is a perfect situation where you would use regular expressions instead of string manipulations:

**Code**

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match("/USD<\\/td>\\s+<td[^>]*>(?<usd_value>[0-9,.-]*)<\\/td>/i", $site, $matches))
    echo $matches["usd_value"];
```

The regex searches `USD` followed by `</td>`, followed by whitespace, then `<td...>` tag. Everything between that `<td...>` and next `</td>` that looks like a number is captured into the group with name `usd_value`

**Output**

```
2,2743
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @WouterHuysentruit, but i´m not real good with regular expressions, with your code i could get other needed values too. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

I found an error:
    `$data2 = explode('</td>',$data[1]);`

should be:

`$data2 = explode('</td>',$data1[1]);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, i just fix the code, was just a misspelled line. The code still don´t work.